# Not executing if statement

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

I have this in a helper function.

```
enum recstate {
    initial,
};

struct client {
    enum recstate state;
}
```

This is in my main code:

```
struct client *p;
p->state = initial;
```

Everything works fine until I try to execute this if statement below:

```
if(p->state == initial){
```

I really don't understand why.
Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: for all we know, you can have a `p->state = somethingElse` in the code that you haven't shown.

Comment: try this `struct client *p=malloc(sizeof(*p));`

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for the structure.

Comment: please show complete code. don't interrupt it with explanation. we know what `main()` is.

Comment: "Not executing if statement" is not a description. tell us what happened! does your app crash?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't allocated memory for `p`. You are accessing unauthorized memory. The behavior of accessing unauthorized memory is not defined.

Add

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
```

before the line

```
p->state = initial;
```